# Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, autowired, sessionfactory

I know that they are a lot of other questions like mine, but I don't seem to find the answer that I need. I'm new to Spring and Hibernate, so I don't understand much yet. I'm using Jetty Runner. Anyway, I was going to start to use Hibernate in my application and I had this error:

```
2018-05-03 15:37:03 ERROR ContextLoader:316 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:559)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
... 42 more
2018-05-03 15:37:03 WARN  WebAppContext:554 - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@b97c004{/DonaRegistration,file:///C:/Users/Asuka/Desktop/DonaRegistration/WebContent/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/Asuka/Desktop/DonaRegistration/WebContent/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:559)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
... 42 more
```

I'm not sure what is happening, can someone help me please?

This is my code:

UsersDao

```
package com.winwel.spring.web.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@Component("usersDao")
public class UsersDao {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //Only when I add this I get my error
    **@Autowired
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;**

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
    }
```

dao-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.winwel.spring.web.dao"/>


    <beans profile="production">
        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

        <bean autowire-candidate="true" id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.winwel.spring.web.dao</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven/>

    </beans>
</beans>
```

I'm using Spring 5.0.4 and Hibernate 5.2.13 and as far as I know they are compatible.

I've tried adding `@Qualifier`, with/without `"autowire-candidate=true"` as well as `@Autowired(required= true)`, I've checked my packages and they look fine. I really don't know what is happening.

If you need anything else feel free to ask.

Comment: "<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name='jdbc/spring' id='dataSource' expected-type='javax.sql.DataSource'/>" until now I've had no problems with this

Comment: I think the class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean should be in the component scan. Can you try to add org.springframework.orm to the component scan ? Btw sorry about my first comment that I deleted I read your conf too fast.

Comment: No problem! I've tried it, but didn't work, the error is still the same, I really don't know what is happening here

Comment: I'm no Spring expert but looking various examples trying to help you I've noticed that property "packagesToScan" in the session bean is usually set pointing to @Entity classes and not DAOs. Maybe you have a conflict there because you have specified the same package in two elements, component-scan and that property. Point the session bean property to your entities package and try again.

Comment: My User class (the one where I use @Entity) and UsersDao are on the same package and if I comment or delete that property "packagesToScan" nothing happens, the error is the same, so that is not the problem. Thanks for trying tho!